# Handle sql exception in Business logic

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, elmah

I have the executenonquery method in Data Access Layer. I need to handle exception in Business logic when executenonquery fails.
I am using Elmah logger in BLL. There is no return value from ExecuteNonQuery method, 
so what condition should I check for in BLL to log for any exception is thrown

BLL:

//constructor

```
public FormService(ISettings settings, ILogger logger, IFormDataServiceWorker formDataService)
            : base(settings, logger)
        {
            this._formDataService = formDataService;
        } 
        //method calling DAL
        public string GetRefNo(FormData formData)
        {
                foreach (var formFieldData in formFieldDataList)
                {
                    this._formDataService.SubmitFormData(formFieldData);
                }
}
```

DAL Implementation:

```
public void SubmitFormData(FormFieldDTO formFieldData)
        {
            using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.DBConnection))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("usp_SubmissionDataInsert", sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@SubmissionId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = formFieldData.SubmissionId;
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldId", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = formFieldData.FieldId;
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = formFieldData.FieldTitle;
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldData", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = formFieldData.FieldValue;
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = formFieldData.FieldName; 

                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/catch and specialised exceptions if you want to catch this exceptions in business layer. Something like this:

```
public class MyDatabaseLevelException : Exception
```

and in your DAL implementation you throw this exception type when any Ado.net exception occurs.

```
throw new MyDatabaseLevelException("message", inner);
```

So in your BLL you will be able to catch this type of exception:

```
public string GetRefNo(FormData formData)
{
    foreach (var formFieldData in formFieldDataList)
    {
        try
        {
            this._formDataService.SubmitFormData(formFieldData);
        }
       catch (MyDatabaseLevelException exception)
       {
            //log or do something with this.
       }
    }
}
```

Said that, I think that database level exceptions should be logged on Database Layer(DAL). So in your case the most appropriate way to achieve this is to log `ExecuteNonQuery` exceptions in `SubmitFormData` method. The business layer should not know how to handle Database problems.